# IPython notebook: export without executing cells?

Tags: python-2.7, markdown, jupyter-notebook

I work predominately in IPython notebook. Normally it's very useful for nbconvert to run all cells and capture the output, however, I sometimes display my notebooks on a webpage where the user can execute the code themselves. In this case, I don't want the output captured, I just want the notebook formatted in markdown. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Nbconvert doesn't execute the code by default, but it exports to a static version of the notebook which you can't directly run or edit. To run code, you need a kernel running somewhere. You might want to look at [binder](http://mybinder.org/) to publish live notebooks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, I think you may've misunderstood my question. I already have a setup to run and edit code on the front-end, so I **do** want a static version of the notebook. However, when nbconvert is run, it  executes all the cells and captures the output. Since I have a way of doing this myself, I don't want any of the output captured. Just markdown, with code cells indented four spaces -- nothing else.

Comment: Nbconvert does not execute your notebook by default. There is an option to do that, but it's off by default. However, if you saved the notebook with the output, nbconvert will include the output when it converts it. To avoid that, you can either clear the output before saving, or use a [custom template](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html) to exclude output when you do the conversion.

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't know that! I will try exporting notebook, without saving output, and see if that works. I looked into custom templates previously, but for now, I'll just try clearing the output.